# "false Transaction mined but execution failed" error when deploying on Remix VM

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain, remix, contract-deployment

I've been trying to clone the Safemoon contract and deploy it on the Remix virtual machine. The contract compiles fine but I get this error when trying to deploy:
[image]

Gas do get deducted from the selected account.
I've tried changing the UniswapV2Router address but didn't work.

What might be the problem? Thanks in advance!